# How to "align" vertically a HStack

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I've got a problem : I am using a ForEach loop to generate a custom view in a view.
I want them to be align like this (I've made this by creating 3 HStack inside a VStack):

[The expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMb5l.png)

But I use ForEach, as a consequence, I am restricted to only "1 Stack".
I'm getting something like this :

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olOfo.png)

Here is the code that concerns only the ScrollView :

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(styles, id: \.id) { style in // styles is an array that stores ids.
                            
                            MusicStyleTabView(style: style, selectedBtn: self.$selected)// This view is the "cell" in question.
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

So how can I align horizontally a VStack ?

Comment: Use a `LazyVGrid`, not an `HStack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is going to solve your problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {
let gridItems = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 60)), count: 2)

var body: some View {
    ScrollView { 
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems) {
            ForEach(styles, id: \.id) { style in
                MusicStyleTabView(style: style , selectedBtn: self.$selected)
            }
        }
    }
}
```